# Does global variable used in a function need to be defined before the def block?

Tags: append, python-3.6

I must admit that I didn't expect the following code could work (code sample from a collegue of mine):

```
def foo():
    li.append(3)
li = [1, 2]
foo()
print(li) # gives [1, 2, 3]
```

My questions are:

- why is 'global li' not needed in the 'def foo()'?
- why is 'li = [1, 2]' not needed to be put before the 'def foo()'?

ps. Python 3.6.1 is used for the listed code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Global keyword is a keyword that allows a user to modify a variable outside of the current scope.

   Rules of global keyword:

   - If a variable is assigned a value anywhere within the function’s
     body, it’s assumed to be a local unless explicitly declared as
     global.
   - Variables that are only referenced inside a function are
     implicitly global.
   - We Use global keyword to use a global variable       inside a
     function.
   - There is no need to use global keyword outside a      function.

Your code , you are not changing or assigning a 'li' value

2.Here list is defined before foo() is called, so it working fine.suppose if you call foo() before li is defined, it will throw a error like NameError: name 'li' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

1. Since the list is defined before foo() is called, hence there is no error.
2. `global` keyword is only required when we want to do assignment or change the global variable. Accessing the methods or printing the variable does not require the `global` keyword